# Как использовать NSLocalizedString для локализации цены inappa?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

Как реализовать локализацию цены за покупку, если используем язык один, а регион совсем др и цену нужно отобразить той страны, которая установлена. Например используем русский язык в регионе франция. Для региона России используем файл localizable.strings(Russian(Russia)), а для др регионов, не имеющих русского языка используем localizable.strings(Russian), интерфейс отображается на русском, но а цена должна соответствовать цене во Франции . Как это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
let priceFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
var text = "" // Прайс
let p = SKProduct() // Ваш продукт
priceFormatter.locale = p.priceLocale
if let price = priceFormatter.string(from: p.price) {
        text = NSLocalizedString("Buy for ", comment: "") + price
}
```

Comment: Добавил скрин в вопрос. Падает на этой строке, чего-то не понимаю ((

Comment: @ArturSkachkov вам нужно использовать полученную **из сети** вашу покупку и у нее брать локаль.